# python: sharing variables between modules

Tags: python

I am trying to share variables between two separate modules in python. In general what I am trying to do is,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
          self.set1 = 0
          self.set2 = 0

    def count(self, data):
        parse throught the data in here...
        self.set1 = data[0:2]
        self.set2 = data[5:20]


-------------------------------------------- 

from moduleA import A

def main():
    data = A()
    print(data.set1)
    print(data.set2)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

but this will not work. it will just print 0 for set1 and set2. i'm not sure how I would get the correct results.

Does anyone know the right approach to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What else would it do?! You never call `data.count` and don't pass any data (you may have confused yourself by naming the class instance the same as a method parameter). It's hard to advise on approach when you don't even say what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You are never calling `count(...)`, the values of `set1` and `set2` will be 0 until you do.

You call `__init__(self)` by instantiating the class with the line:

```
data = A()
```

This sets both `data.set1` and `data.set2` to 0.

---

**Update**: following OP's comment.

When you create a new `A` object in your main module, you are creating a new instance of that object.  Each instance has it's own version of its attributes, so if I did:

```
data1 = A()
data2 = A()
data1.set1 = "some value"
```

Then the following would be false:

```
data1.set1 == data2.set1
```

Both objects get their own set of instance attributes.

To acheive what you want, you can do two (sensible) things:

- Store the data on the *class* itself
- Have a singleton object that is declared in `ModuleA` and that all the other modules use

If will elaborate or both below.

**Class Attributes**

If you declare an attribute in the class definition, instead of the `**init**(self, ...) method, those attributes are shared between every instance, at least initially.

An example:

```
class A(object):
     a = []
```

Now if I do this:

```
 data1 = A()
 data2 = A()
 data1.a.append('some value')
```

Then `data1.a` and `data2.a` will both be the same list, with the same values.

Like I said, this is only *initially*, if you ever assign to `a`, then they will be referencing different things, and won't be the same.  I could re-bind `data1.a` to something else, and `data2.a` would have the original value:

```
 data1.a = ["another value"]
 print(data1.a) # prints ["another value"]
 print(data2.a) # prints ["some value"]
```

If you want all `A` objects to share that attribute value, you must never assign to it for a particular instance, because then that instance will have its own value.

**"Singleton" object**

Instead of creating a new object `data` in main, you could declare a single object of type a in `ModuleA`:

```
 class A(object):
      ...

 data = A()
```

Now, in your main module you can use it like this:

```
 from ModuleA import data
 print(data.set1)
```

But you must always ensure that all your modules use *that* single object, and don't create their own `A`s.

Comment: I understand that. However, if I do call count I would have to pass something in for data, but I just want to be able to access the variables inside it. the count function is being used by other modules as well, but for main() I just want to be able to access them

Comment: You are then looking for a singleton(ish) pattern.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Even if I declare data = A() within moduleA, i still will not have access to the variables within count(self, data)

Comment: set1 and set2 would still have values of 0

Comment: You said that "other modules" use the count function.  You are not being very clear what exactly you expect to happen...

Comment: Sorry. So what I am trying to do is that I have this moduleA which has the function count with parameter data. There are other modules that will call count() and pass in specific set  of data. The count method will then take that data and use it to assign values to set1 and set2.

Then I have this main function that needs to just access the set1 and set2 variables, but in order to do that I need to call count

The problem is that if I call count I must pass in something for the data parameter...simply saying data = A() will not give me access to the updated values of set1 and set2

Comment: It will do if you call whatever code it is in those other modules that calls `count(...)`.  Those modules must call count on the `data` that is in `ModuleA`.  How else do you expect that data to appear if you don't ever call `count`...?